# Pass a custom selector delegate to LINQ's GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

So I have this extension that returns a `KeyValuePair` of the duplicate items (Keys) and their corresponding indices (Value) in an `IEnumerable`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TSource, int[]>> GetDuplicates<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> e)
    {
        return e.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                .Select(xg => new KeyValuePair<TSource, int[]>(xg.Key, xg.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray()))
                .Where(kv => kv.Value.Length > 1);
    }
```

I'm trying to do a very basic thing - I want to inject a custom selector so that I could pass into `GroupBy` - I tried this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TSource, int[]>> GetDuplicates<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> e, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        return e.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
                .GroupBy(x => selector(x.Value))
                .Select(xg => new KeyValuePair<TSource, int[]>(xg.Key, xg.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray()))
                .Where(kv => kv.Value.Length > 1);
    }
```

But I got invalid arguments errors in the newing up of the `KeyValuePair`.

It seems that I'm getting confused with all the generic arguments that should be passed - I'm not sure how to hook them up :s

I think the problem here is that the selector should return the anonymous type that the first `Select` projected - and not TKey - but how can I inject an anonymous type generic arg?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Found a workaround - not that great, but it works and shows what I want.

```
    private static List<TSource> GetDups<TSource, TKey>(List<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
    {
        var dupGosIndices = source
            .Select(selector)
            .GetDuplicates().Select(x => x.Value);

        var dupGos = new List<TSource>();
        foreach (IEnumerable<int> indicesList in dupGosIndices) {
            dupGos.Add(source[indicesList.ElementAt(0)]);
        }
        return dupGos;
    }
```

Comment: How you have defined `selector`? What is return type?

Comment: Hmm? - it says it in the code `Func<TSource, TKey> selector` (returns `TKey` - I got the values from the selector of `GroupBy`)

Comment: Could you show the selector code?

Comment: If i understand correctly the point the of the selector is to say "please give me back the duplicates that are duplicating on this property?"  correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this? The grouping on `IGrouping<Key, IEnumerable<TSource>>` will all have the same TSource values, so go ahead and grab the first one.

```
            return e.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
                .GroupBy(x => selector(x.Value))
                .Select(xg => new KeyValuePair<TSource, int[]>(xg.Select(x => x.Value).First(), xg.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray()))
                .Where(kv => kv.Value.Length > 1);
```